# Selenium Chrome Driver Limitations Web Scraping at Scale

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm planning to use Selenium Chrome Driver for my project which will be used to do web scraping to multiple public websites (something like kayak or skyscanner). So there will be a REST GET endpoint where my backend would launch headless Chrome to scrape multiple websites, and eventually return a manipulated JSON.

I want to know how scalable is Chrome Driver as it sounds like a headless Chrome instance needs to be launched whenever a request comes in.

Updated: Question using Google Chrome Headless

Comment: Was this question heavily edited?  The answers are mentioning Phantom.js, but the question doesn't mention Phantom.js.  (And nobody is addressing running Chromedriver at scale, which is what the current form of the question is about.)

Answer (score 3):

Please find the pros and cons of phantom js  which I noticed during implementation .Hope this helps.

> Cons:

```
1)It will fail to recognize the browser elements like id,xpath,csselector
when compared to chrome driver.
2)If you have login mechanism ,redirects won't work as you expect when compared to chrome driver.
3)You need to manually implement the custom logic for screen shots for the test failures if you need it.
4)If you want to switch between multiple drivers like chrome,html etc then it is very difficult
```

> Pros:

```
1)Test case execution is faster when compared to chrome driver
2)No browser is required it will run without GUI. 
3)No much configurations are needed when compared to chromedriver.
```

You can go with html driver also which is quite faster then phantom but even it has its own limitations that you need take care of before implementation.

Comment: it cannot recognize id attribute? can you pls share about performance issue too? is it feasible for my use case above?

Comment: yes most of the times it will fail to recognize the id.Performance depends on how much big your project is and how much business logic your code has .If it is huge then it will be very poor compared to Chrome driver.

Comment: I think for your use case I would suggest to go with chrome since making a webservice calls and getting a response is quite time consuming in phantom for assertions.You can gave a try since it is very difficult to say without seeing the code.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that you really need to use PhantomJS.

Chrome implemented "headless" mode couple of months ago.
"Headless Chrome" does the same job that PhantomJS, and does it better. 
I heard that PhantomJS authors even said that they will not support it anymore.

You can enable headless mode in Selenide with just on line:

```
Configuration.headless = true;
```

Comment: I'm trying to find out if it is feasible to use headless browser for scraping workflows like this. I tried the non headless chrome and it's very slow compared to htmlunit, as it has to actually launch the browser app, and go to the website and then scrape the data...what if there's millions of request to scrape the website?

Answer (score 1):

Did you think about headless chrome?
[Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

Comment: I know about this but I don't think this is stable yet

Comment: hmm yes but the question remains same, is it feasible to serve large number of requests where we are going to be launching headless chrome each time a request comes in?