# Phantom js unable to locate web elements

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to locate web elements in a web page using selenium java with phantomjs driver. 
I am able to load the web page but ending up with unable to locate the element error.

Here is what I am using: windows 7, selenium 3 and phantom 2.1.1.

I have also added the phantomjs driver path to environment variable.

Comment: Hi Poojitha phantom js has some limitations with browser elements detection.Even I too faced the same issue multiple times.Could you please let me know what browser elements it is trying to find I mean id,xpath or css. Please paste your snippet . Is there any specific reason why you chose phantom js?

Comment: Please do also read this post where I have specified pros and cons

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47038698/selenium-phantomjsdriver-limitations-web-scraping-at-scale/47039130#47039130

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: this is how i am trying to locate browser elements
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(pwd);
driver.findElement(By.id("btn_signin")).click();